# How to create Android sepolicy based on the denial "execute_no_trans"?

Tags: security, scripts, selinux

I am trying to execute my script `/vendor/bin/init.inmod.sh` using below method:

Script `init.inmod.sh`:

```
#!/shebang???

/vendor/bin/test_disp hdcp disable
```

In vendor specific `.rc` file:

```
on ???
    start inmod_sh

service inmod_sh /vendor/bin/init.inmod.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root system
    disabled
    oneshot
```

My file context:

```
(vendor|system/vendor)/bin/init\.inmod\.sh    u:object_r:init_inmod_sh_exec:s0
```

And my `init_inmod_sh.te`:

```
type init_inmod_sh, domain;
type init_inmod_sh_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;
init_daemon_domain(init_inmod_sh);

allow init_inmod_sh vendor_shell_exec:file rx_file_perms;
allow init_inmod_sh vendor_toolbox_exec:file rx_file_perms;
allow init_inmod_sh self:capability { sys_module sys_admin };

allow init_inmod_sh system_file:system module_load;
allow init_inmod_sh vendor_file:system module_load;
allow init_inmod_sh debugfs_pvr:dir r_dir_perms;

allow init_inmod_sh ampservice:unix_stream_socket { connectto };
allow init_inmod_sh ampservice:unix_dgram_socket { sendto };
allow init_inmod_sh ion_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;

allow init_inmod_sh init_inmod_sh_exec:file { execute_no_trans getattr execute read open };
permissive init_inmod_sh;
```

I am getting below error:

```
02-14 00:31:34.580 221 221 I init.inmod.sh: type=1400 audit(0.0:4): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for path="/vendor/bin/test_disp" dev="dm-1" ino=274 scontext=u:r:init_inmod_sh:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

Why am I getting the `execute_no_trans` denial even after I set `.sh` file to `permissive`?

Comment: Please complete missing parts of your question (highlighted with ???). Did you resolve the problem? If yes, you can answer your question yourself for future visitors. Btw development questions are off-topic here.

Comment: The apparent reason is that your script isn't getting the context `u:object_r:init_inmod_sh_exec:s0`, instead the general context of vendor partition: `u:object_r:vendor_file:s0`. Did you try `restorecon -v /vendor/bin/init.inmod.sh` or `chcon u:object_r:init_inmod_sh_exec:s0 /vendor/bin/init.inmod.sh`?